# Ultimate Membership Pro Plugin for Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, membership

I have a template that has a database named "profiles" which has some specific fields, useful for my purpose.
I am using Ultimate Membership Pro as a plugin. Through this plugin's Register form, a new user is added as WP user. I want to connect this registry form with the "Profiles" database but I can't. 
Any Ideas???

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen? All users will be added with the "subscriber" role.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/